# How do spells measure time?

Tags: baldurs-gate-2-enhanced

In real time terms what are the units of time that spell and effects use in Baldur's Gate 2: Enhanced Edition?

I mean the times such as Casting Time, Turn, Round, Hours, etc.

[image: Casting Time]

[image: Turns]

[image: Rounds]

[image: Hours]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

https://forums.beamdog.com/discussion/13885/durations-descriptions-list-of-issues

1 day in game = 24 hours in-game = 1200 rounds = 7200 seconds

1 hour = 5 Turns = 50 rounds = 300 seconds

1 turn = 10 rounds = 60 seconds

1 round = 6 seconds

I presume cast time is in rounds and that duration turn is upon the person's turn.

Notice: Some spell time/duration description are inconsistency in defining time/duration so beware.

Comment: Note that these work for 30 fps. Else, multiply (real-life) seconds by 30/FPS. Eg, on 60 FPS, 1 game hour = 50 rounds = 150 seconds

Answer (score 2):

Casting time is in tenths of a round.
Casting time 1 = 0.6 second
Casting time 9 = 5.4 seconds